# Understanding Windows local password hashes (NTLM)

Tags: hash, windows, ntlm, windows-7

I have recently dumped some hashes from my local machine because I'm trying to understand the process in which Windows 7 hashes it's passwords.

I have discovered my local password hash that looks (*similar*) to this: `Jason:502:aad3c435b514a4eeaad3b935b51304fe:c46b9e588fa0d112de6f59fd6d58eae3:::`

Now what I would like to know is what the different sections mean, so:

We have this hash: `Jason:502:aad3c435b514a4eeaad3b935b51304fe:c46b9e588fa0d112de6f59fd6d58eae3:::` that looks to be separated by `:` if we separate this by the `:` we end up with this:

```
[Jason, :, 502, :, aad3c435b514a4eeaad3b935b51304fe, :, c46b9e588fa0d112de6f59fd6d58eae3, :, :, :]
```

- I'm assuming the first part `Jason` is the username, that's the most logical to me.
- The third part `aad3c435b514a4eeaad3b935b51304fe` is the ntlm hash would be my best guess.

If my assumption is correct then that leaves `c46b9e588fa0d112de6f59fd6d58eae3` and `502` left.

- I'd guess that the other hash (`c46b9e588fa0d112de6f59fd6d58eae3`) is the derived key, that is created from the password itself.
- The `502` would be the binary data of the user.
- And the `:` is just a separator or a padding.

Now for my question, am I correct in my assumptions on what each part of the hash represents? If not can someone please explain to me what each part represents?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using

```
[Jason, :, 502, :, aad3c435b514a4eeaad3b935b51304fe, :, c46b9e588fa0d112de6f59fd6d58eae3, :, :, :]
```

as the example

- `Jason` is the user name
- `502` is the relative identifier (500 is an administrator, 502 here is a kerberos account.)  (adsecurity.org/?p=483)
- `aad3c435b514a4eeaad3b935b51304f` is the LM hash
- `c46b9e588fa0d112de6f59fd6d58eae3` is the NT hash

Details on difference between the hashes can be found here:
[LM / NT Hashes](http://www.adshotgyan.com/2012/02/lm-hash-and-nt-hash.html)

Comment: So that would make this entire hash the NTLM hash, correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "this entire hash"?  The NTLM hash is only the string `c46b9e588fa0d112de6f59fd6d58eae3` as @iain explained.

Comment: Why is there an NTLM & LM hash. I thought NTLM hash superceded an LM hash as it was not secure?

Comment: You can prevent it with a  NoLM Hash Policy https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/299656/how-to-prevent-windows-from-storing-a-lan-manager-hash-of-your-passwor

Comment: I can see @13aal's confusion. If there's a more secure hashing algorithm to LM being utilised on a system (NTLM), then why still implement LM hashes instead of completely replacing it with the newer, more secure one? Why maim the security benefits of a stronger hash algorithm by including it alongside a weaker one that can be used to easily compromise the system anyway?

Comment: Adding to this, even though it's a long time since it was opened. 

The link that ~@iainpb posted explains it all.
[link](http://www.adshotgyan.com/2012/02/lm-hash-and-nt-hash.html)

`The LM hash is stored for backward compatibility reasons. Many environments no longer need it and can disable storage of that value.`

In my experience, the LM hash is always disabled on newer versions of Windows.